# Сгенерировать случайное слово из заданного алфавита

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написать программу, генерирующую некоторое случайное слово, состоящее из букв заданного алфавита.
Алфавит “A01#”, число символов в генерируемом слове не более 70. Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать код

```
import random
s=input ()
a="A01#"
k=randit (0,70)
print (s, random.choice(a))
```

Comment: Уважаемая @Ирина, давайте вопросам такие названия, чтобы сразу было понятно, ЧТО ИМЕННО Вам нужно.

Comment: `"".join(random.choices(a, k=random.randint(0, 70)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так в цикле можно добавлять рандомные буквы из вашего алфавита в новую строку.

```
import random
a="A01#"
print(''.join([random.choice(a) for i in range(random.randint(0,70))]))
```